# How to pass files to native modules and vice versa in react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-native-module

I want to `encrypt/decrypt files` in native side using react-native. So I need to pass `files` such as Images, Videos, docs from javascript side to java code and back from java code to javascript side.

How can I do it ?